# Como posso copiar itens de uma lista para outra

Tags: android, listview

Desejo criar uma `listview`com dados de outra `listview`.
Ele vai funcionar como um carrinho desses sites de compra, porem servira para outra finalidade.

Numa lista haverá

> linha >`imageview`, `textview`, `imagebutton`

Na outra listview

> linha> `Imageview` da primeira da primeira lista, `textview` da primeira lista e `imagebutton` para excluir

de que modo posso fazer isso?

sendo que já tenho a primeira `listview` pronta

Comment: Onde estão os dados da Listview? É um ArraList? A segunda ListView terá o mesmo número de linhas que a primeira?

Comment: De que tipo é essa lista: List, Arraylist, etc?

Comment: a primeira é ArrayList, a segunda eu devo fazer o mesmo?

Comment: Se os dados das duas listas são os mesmos use o mesmo ArrayList nos dois adapters.

Comment: não, a segunda só receberá dados caso eu clique no botão para adicionar.

Comment: porem só recebera dados da mesma linha do botão

Comment: Então use outro Arraylist, adicione a ele um item cada vez que o botão adicionar for clicado. Use esse ArrayList no adapter da outra ListView.

Comment: isso ira funcionar com um botão né?

e caso eu tenha 3 itens na primeira lista? cada um terá um botão se eu clicar no segundo ou no terceiro, vai funcionar igual?

Comment: Depende da implementação, pode ter só um botão que actue na linha seleccionada ou ter um botão por cada linha. O adapter não será muito diferente do da primeira lista só difere a ação do(s) botão(ões).

Comment: eu vou tentar, depois dou feedback.

Comment: preciso colocar algo no onclick ou só preciso checar se ele é clicado pra add no arraylist 2?